# Faster way of splitting string in C++

Tags: c++, string, substring

I have a string of length 5 million to break into substrings of desired length (5 or 10 or ...). and store the fragments into a vector. The way I do it seems to take ages. Looking for an ultra fast method.

Example code how i do it. [Test here](http://cpp.sh/4gxxi)

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
   std::vector<std::string> splits;
   std::string text = "ABCDBCDAACBDAADCADACBBCDACDADBCAACDBCADACD";

   for(int i = 0; i < text.length() ; i+= 5)
   {
     splits.push_back(text.substr (i, 5));
     std::cout << "splits: " << text.substr(i, 5) << std::endl;

   }

}
```

Comment: if the length is fixed why do you need to split it?

Comment: There is a high chance you don't actually need `splits`. It is most likely enough to customly iterate over `text` to spit out string pieces. And those string pieces most likely don't even need to be `std::string`s, instead you want something like a [string_view](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/basic_string_view).

Comment: Both actions `push_back` and output are quite slow. You should avoid any output and implement the storage in a faster way. For example, preallocate storage in your vector with `splits.resize` and store things using `splits[i]=` or `strcpy(split[i], ..`

Comment: @arashkordi I need to split to represent each split of string with some other representation.

Comment: do something smarter, the strings are all 5 characters, you can retrieve the `Nth` string at any time with a simple offset calculation, when you actually need it. And having to deal only with `const char*`, you won't need to construct a new string for every split.

Comment: @nwp Thanks for your comment. I'l have a look on that

Comment: Apart from not breaking the string, you might want to compile your code in release mode. Additionally, if you are using windows don't type string to screen, it take ages for windows command line emulator to display text.

Comment: @Michael Thanks, actually I use `splits.resize()` in my original code, but need to try with `=` or `strcpy`.

Comment: @dau_sama . Do you mean to say that `text.substr (i, 5)` is creating a new string each time.

Comment: @CemKalyoncu I am on linux , and that too using terminal.

Comment: in release build without printing every substring this code takes only a few seconds with a 65MB string.

Comment: @AwaitedOne it does, but it's probably optimized out. The real problem is that you save all your strings to another string vector. You just need a representation of that data, not a copy. This is if you want to make things fast, if not, your solution is pretty standard and good for the job.

Comment: How about not splitting, but only keep indices+lengths of the substrings

Comment: If you want to keep the vector solution, how about pre-reserving the vector size? Something similar to `splits.reserve((text.length() + 4) / 5);` (I didn't check accuracy of my arithmetic)

Comment: @Awaited - `strcpy` into a `std::string` is definitely *not* recommended. Creating a new string in `substr` is not that bad, as you need a new string anyway, to store in the vector.

Comment: Can't you store the actual text in a single `vector`/`string`and store just indices into this storage?

Comment: @BoPersson Thanks. Actually I badly need to know the substring to know its position in the other vector.  it takes approx `33sec` to split  a string of 5 million, but i am worried about the growing string length which may be of 100 million.

Comment: @graham.reeds Not sure if i follow.

Comment: @AwaitedOne Store the data in a container and then use another container to store indices into that data.

Answer (score 2):

This will be a little bit faster.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
   std::vector<std::string> splits;
   std::string text = "ABCDBCDAACBDAADCADACBBCDACDADBCAACDBCADACD";

   // Start timing
   splits.reserve( (text.length()+5-1)/5 );

   const auto end = text.begin() +(text.length()/5)*5;
   auto it = text.begin();
   for(; it < end; it += 5)
   {
     splits.emplace_back(it, it+5);
   }

   if (it != text.end())
   {
       splits.emplace_back(it,text.end());
   }
   //end timing

   for (const auto& str : splits)
   {
       std::cout << "splits: " << str << std::endl;
   }
}
```

Rather than creating a new string with `substr`, and then copying that string into the vector, it creates the string directly.  To make this as simple as possible, the main loop only creates full length strings, and then any partial string at the end is handled separately.

It also removes the printing from the timing loop (if you really are doing that, don't! IO is slow).

Finally enough space is reserved in the vector before creating the strings (although I notice you say in the comments you are doing that).

Having said all that, an alternative representation where you don't use std::string, but just use an offset + length in `text` will be much faster still.

Given that you know you are only holding short strings, a separate class which has a fixed length array (15 bytes?) plus a length (1 byte).  Might be an intermediate step.  glibc doesn't have the short string optimization, so allocating 20 million chunks of memory won't be that fast.

Final thought:  You have enabled optimization, haven't you?  It will make a *huge* difference.